# Probability of Getting a ball different from all others before it

Tags: probability

Suppose there are $n$ balls in a box labelled $1,2...n$ and $n$ draws are made from the box **with replacement**.  If $X_{i}=\text{Label on the ball drawn on the i-th draw}$ . What is the probability that $X_{i}\neq X_{j}\,\forall \,\,j\leq i-1$ ?

How do I compute this . The main problem I am facing is the with replacement part.

Here's how I tried to solve it . $P(X_{i}\neq X_{j}\forall\,j\leq i-1)=1-P(X_{i}=X_{j}\,\,\text{for some}\,\,j\leq i-1)$

. Now if $k$ of $X_{j}$'s are equal. Then it can happen in $\binom{n}{1}\cdot\frac{(i-1)!}{k!}=n\cdot\frac{(i-1)!}{k!}$ ways.
And all other $i-1-k$ $X_{j}$'s are unequal. This can happen in $\binom{n-1}{i-1-k}$ ​And each of them has probability $\frac{1}{n^{i}}$ .Then the probability that :-

$$P(X_{i}=X_{j}\,\,\text{for some}\,\,j\leq i-1)=1-\frac{1}{n^{i}}\sum_{k=1}^{i-1}n\cdot\frac{(i-1)!}{k!}\binom{n-1}{i-1-k}$$

However I feel I am not getting this correct. There are holes in my arguments which are not getting clear to me.

Can anyone help me out on this?. How and where did I go wrong and what is the correct method to approach this?.

Edit:- I actually see my mistakes now. But anyways can please someone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Rather than pulling for $X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots$ *and then* pulling $X_i$ and asking if $X_i$ is different than all pulls that happened before it... try pulling $X_i$ *first* and then only after pulling for $X_i$ do you pull for $X_1,X_2,\dots$.  This should be a much easier way to think of this and you should be able to convince yourself that the probability will match.

Comment: It will be $\Pr(X_i\neq X_j~~\forall j~1\leq j\leq i-1) = \Pr(X_1\neq X_j~~\forall j~ 2\leq j\leq i) = (\frac{n-1}{n})^{i-1}$

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is $(\frac{n-1}{n})^{i-1}$ isn't it?

Comment: @ArghyadeepChatterjee No, JMoravitz is correct, the exponent should be $i-1$.

Comment: Yeah. I messed up the latex and exponent . Lol. After @JMoravitz 's comment . It instantly became clear to me what I was supposed to do.

Comment: To emphasize... the question of "*what if $k$ of the $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{i-1}$ were equal*" is a dangerous and tedious way to think of the problem which leads to some pretty awful calculations.  That is not to say that it was necessarily *wrong*... but it is by no means recommended nor convenient or easy.

Comment: Thanks. After just seeing your first comment it immediately clicked for me and I knew what I had to do. @JMoravitz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WLOG, let's say the $i^\text{th}$ draw is the ball numbered $n$. Then we must only draw at most the balls numbered $1$ to $n-1$ in the previous $i-1$ draws.

Since each of these draws has $n-1$ choices so that they are not the ball numbered $n$, there are $(n-1)^{i-1}$ ways to validly pick these first $i-1$ balls. Since each draw has $n$ total choices of the ball picked, the probability is
$$\frac{(n-1)^{i-1}}{n^{i-1}}$$
$$=\boxed{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{i-1}}$$